# C++ throwing exception illegal

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Getting an error : illegal use of this typename
This is the `operator+` overloading :

```
    template<class T>
        inline Vec<T> Vec<T>::operator+(const Vec& rhs) const
        {
            int vecSize = 0;
            if (rhs.size() == 0 || size() == 0) {
                throw ExceptionEmptyOperand;
            }
            if (rhs.size() != size()) {
                throw ExceptionWrongDimensions;
            }
            else
            {
                Vec<T> vec;
                vecSize = rhs.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < vecSize;i++) {
                    vec.push(*this[i] + rhs[i])
            }

return vec;
        }
```

This is the declaration of the `operator[]` overload :

```
  T& operator[](unsigned int ind);
    const T& operator[](unsigned int ind) const;
```

The first one was made to be able to change the vector values.

This what I've tried to do and getting an error as above:

```
template<class T>
inline T& Vec<T>::operator[](unsigned int ind) 
{
    list<T>::iterator it = vals_.begin();
    if (size() == 0) {
        throw ExceptionEmptyOperand;
    }
    if (size() < ind) {
        throw ExceptionIndexExceed;
    }


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<ind; i++) {
            ++it;
        }
        return *it;
    }
```

it's giving me this error : ExceptionEmptyOperand illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: What you tried for those implementation ? What issue you are facing ?

Comment: you forgot to return the result in `operator+`

Comment: where do you store the actual values?

Comment: What about (*this)[i]   (subscript [] is higher precedence to dereference *)

Comment: @tobi303 I just didnt paste the whole implementation by mistake.
Edited now

Comment: it's giving me this error  : ExceptionEmptyOperand illegal use of this type as an expression.

Comment: Don't you have to call the constructor when you throw? `throw ExceptionEmptyOperand();` instead of `throw ExceptionEmptyOperand;`? http://ideone.com/rAlCRl

Comment: @clcto I found out what the problem is : 
I have to add these lines :
`ExceptionEmptyOperand el1;
   throw el1;`

Comment: Or you could just do as I said and not create a temporary. You should add and accept an answer

Comment: @clcto How can I accept your comment as the "Answer" to my question?

Comment: @sijaanhallak I added an answer. You accept by clicking the check mark next to the score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a type `ExceptionEmptyOperand` then `throw ExceptionEmptyOperand;` is invalid syntax. You need to create an object of that type and then throw it:

```
throw ExceptionEmptyOperand();

// or
ExceptionEmptyOperand e;
throw e;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T>
    inline Vec<T> Vec<T>::operator+(const Vec& rhs) const
    {
        int vecSize = 0;
        if (rhs.size() == 0 || size() == 0) {
            throw ExceptionEmptyOperand;
        }
        if (rhs.size() != size()) {
            throw ExceptionWrongDimensions;
        }
        Vec<T> vec;
        vecSize = rhs.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < vecSize;i++) {
            vec.push((*this)[i] + rhs[i])
        return vec;
    }


template<class T>
inline T& Vec<T>::operator[](unsigned int ind) 
{
    if (size() == 0) {
        throw ExceptionEmptyOperand;
    }
    if (size() <= ind) {
        throw ExceptionIndexExceed;
    }

    list<T>::iterator it = vals_.begin();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<ind; i++) {
            ++it;
    }
    return *it;
}

template<class T>
inline const T& Vec<T>::operator[](unsigned int ind) const
{
    if (size() == 0) {
        throw ExceptionEmptyOperand;
    }
    if (size() <= ind) {
        throw ExceptionIndexExceed;
    }
    list<T>::const_iterator it = vals_.begin();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<ind; i++) {
        ++it;
    }
    return *it;
}
```